# verify email after user have register, laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know , just need write: `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`
But, I should change name of url in router, so, I write:

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Auth'],function(){

    Route::GET('/dang-nhap','LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::POST('/dang-nhap', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::GET('/dang-xuat', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    Route::GET('/dang-ky', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::POST('/dang-ky', 'RegisterController@register');

    Route::GET('/mat-khau/dat-lai-mat-khau', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    Route::POST('/mat-khau/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::GET('/mat-khau/dat-lai-mat-khau/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::POST('/mat-khau/dat-lai-mat-khau', 'ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');

    Route::GET('email/verify', 'VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
    Route::GET('email/verify/{id}', 'VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
    Route::GET('email/resend', 'VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');

});
```

The end, I dont know how to verify email for registerController.
Please help me.

Comment: I too change view for Auth, reason is I have one page login another in "amin/login".

Answer (score 0):

You can call php artisan route:list in terminal to compare your routing with autogenerated